# Could not find xmlsec1 config. Are libxmlsec1-dev and pkg-config installed?

Tags: python-3.x, rhel7, xmlsec1

This is happing especially on RHEL
Already installed this packages  yum install libxml2-devel xmlsec1-devel xmlsec1-openssl-devel libtool-ltdl-devel

```
Could not find xmlsec1 config. Are libxmlsec1-dev and pkg-config installed


Command "/usr/local/pyenv/versions/3.6.5/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-ucm4xpg5/xmlsec/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-gr0ttbdf/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-ucm4xpg5/xmlsec/
```

Why I am getting this error Even though I installed the required packages

Comment: Please format code for readability. Also, you do not ask a specific question.

Comment: Do you have `pkg-config` installed (like it says?)?

Comment: I have installed pkg-config still it is showing this Error

Answer (score 45):

For `Debian`

```
sudo apt-get install libxmlsec1-dev pkg-config
```

try this it will work!

For `RHEL`

```
sudo yum install xmlsec1-devel pkg-config
```

For `MacOS`

```
brew install Libxmlsec1
brew install pkg-config
```

Comment: I was having a problem installing xmlsec. Installed the libraries you've mentioned on MacOS part, and then installed xmlsec following this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63999596/5186565