# ERROR: Could not build wheels for bcrypt which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Tags: python, pycharm, bcrypt

The interpreter configuration in pycharm became invalid for some reason so I created a new virtual environment for the project that I was working on, and installed the dependencies again. But I am having trouble in installing bcrypt again. Here's the complete error. The project was working fine with the previous interpreter so I doubt that the python version has anything to do with it.  I tried installing wheel as well as the error said `could not build wheels` but that didn't do the job as well.

The complete error:

```
Collecting flask-bcrypt
      Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1d/c0/6d4c04d007d72b355de24e7a223978d1a95732245f
    9e9becbf45d3024bf8/Flask-Bcrypt-0.7.1.tar.gz
    Requirement already satisfied: Flask in c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-3
    2\lib\site-packages (from flask-bcrypt) (1.1.2)
    Collecting bcrypt (from flask-bcrypt)
      Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d8/ba/21c475ead997ee21502d30f76fd93ad8d5858d19a3
    fad7cd153de698c4dd/bcrypt-3.2.0.tar.gz
      Installing build dependencies ... done
      Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
        Preparing wheel metadata ... done
    Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.10.1 in c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\p
    ython38-32\lib\site-packages (from Flask->flask-bcrypt) (2.11.2)
    Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=0.15 in c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\p
    ython38-32\lib\site-packages (from Flask->flask-bcrypt) (1.0.1)
    Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=0.24 in c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\pyth
    on\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from Flask->flask-bcrypt) (1.1.0)
    Requirement already satisfied: click>=5.1 in c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\pytho
    n38-32\lib\site-packages (from Flask->flask-bcrypt) (7.1.2)
    Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.4.1 in c:\users\User\appdata\roaming\python\python38\sit
    e-packages (from bcrypt->flask-bcrypt) (1.15.0)
    Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.1 in c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python
    38-32\lib\site-packages (from bcrypt->flask-bcrypt) (1.14.2)
    Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python
    \python38-32\lib\site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.10.1->Flask->flask-bcrypt) (1.1.1)
    Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python
    38-32\lib\site-packages (from cffi>=1.1->bcrypt->flask-bcrypt) (2.20)
    Building wheels for collected packages: bcrypt
      Building wheel for bcrypt (PEP 517) ... error
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: 'c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' 'c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.p
    y' build_wheel 'C:\conda_temp\tmpgl0zt2ul'
           cwd: C:\conda_temp\pip-install-9i9ne9yb\bcrypt
      Complete output (15 lines):
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win32-3.8
      creating build\lib.win32-3.8\bcrypt
      copying src\bcrypt\__about__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\bcrypt
      copying src\bcrypt\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\bcrypt
      copying src\bcrypt\py.typed -> build\lib.win32-3.8\bcrypt
      running build_ext
      generating cffi module 'build\\temp.win32-3.8\\Release\\_bcrypt.c'
      creating build\temp.win32-3.8
      creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release
      building '_bcrypt' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://vi
    sualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
      ----------------------------------------
      ERROR: Failed building wheel for bcrypt
      Running setup.py clean for bcrypt
    Failed to build bcrypt
    ERROR: Could not build wheels for bcrypt which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
    WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 20.2.2 is available.
    You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear: `error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pip error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44951456/pip-error-microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required)

Comment: @C.Nivs I have Visual Studio as well but I am working on Pycharm

Comment: Right, the link installs the build tools for C++, and doesn't require VS

Comment: @C.Nivs can you please tell me what exactly do I need to install from that link?

Comment: @C.Nivs and my problem is in Pycharm, what good would installing vs tools do?

Comment: To install the build tools, you should be able to download them from [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/)

Comment: It's not visual studio, it's visual c++, and it needs it to build the wheels for the package you are installing

Comment: @C.Nivs ohh okay thanks for your help

Answer (score 28):

try using these commands:

```sh
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
python -m pip install --no-use-pep517 bcrypt
```

Comment: python -m pip install --upgrade pip

Comment: `--no-use-pep517` is a brilliant suggestion, `bcrypt` was installed with no headache using this option.

Comment: It didn't fix my problem at first. Then I've installed these libraries using brew and then used your answer and it's fixed. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56700040/5186565

Comment: I am working via Visual studio Code IDE and just this ```python -m pip install --upgrade pip``` solved the code for me. later I just reinstalled bcrypt via ```pip install bcrypt ``` and solved!

Comment: bcrypt was installed with this solution but the rest requirements, like bsdiff4 and numpy, failed although all the Microsoft Visual C++ versions are installed.

Answer (score 5):

`bcrypt` is now implemented in `Rust`. Users building from source will need to have a Rust compiler available although nothing will change for users downloading wheels.

`bcrypt` developers no longer ship `manylinux2010` wheels. Users should upgrade to the latest `pip` to ensure this doesn’t cause issues downloading wheels on their platform or use an older version than `4.0.0`.

So try

```
pip3 install -U "bcrypt<4.0.0"
```

Comment: Actually installing version 4.0.0. helped in my case :)

Comment: This solution worked with my `Python 3.6` and `pip 21.2`. I was trying to install `bcrypt 4.1` from source and it failed. Switching to lower `bcrypt 3.6` worked!

Answer (score 2):

What I did might work for you also:

```bash
$ python -m pip install --upgrade pip
$ python -m pip install --no-use-pep517 bcrypt
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Fixing `bcrypt` to 3.2.2 (the latest version before 4.0.0) fixed this for me. Like stated [here](https://github.com/adriankumpf/teslamate/discussions/2881#discussioncomment-3786381):

> The problem comes with bcrypt 4.0.0 for which there is no wheel available.

Answer (score 0):

Changing python from 32-version to 64-version may be solution. It helped me.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by upgrading my pip version:

`python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

After that, I successfully installed the flask-bcrypt package:

`pip install flask-bcrypt`

Answer (score -1):

try

```
pip install pep517
```

PIP is very unreliable, it needs over 350 different packages under python, and the system  as well

Answer (score -1):

I downloaded and installed

"microsoft visual c++ build tools"
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691126

and restarted the computer and worked for me.