# Can't install xmlsec using PIP command

Tags: python, pip, xmlsec

`pip install xmlsec` commands throws the below error.

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/xxx/PycharmProjects/saml_impl/saml_impl/venv/bin/python /home/sathia/PycharmProjects/saml_impl/saml_impl/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py build_wheel /tmp/tmpu_b5m5vz
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-gblz98sr/xmlsec
  Complete output (14 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  package init file 'src/xmlsec/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/xmlsec
  copying src/xmlsec/py.typed -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/xmlsec
  copying src/xmlsec/template.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/xmlsec
  copying src/xmlsec/constants.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/xmlsec
  copying src/xmlsec/__init__.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/xmlsec
  copying src/xmlsec/tree.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/xmlsec
  running build_ext
  error: Unable to invoke pkg-config.
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for xmlsec
Failed to build xmlsec
ERROR: Could not build wheels for xmlsec which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly'
```

I don't know how to resolve this issue. I tried to install other xmlsec package too, nothing worked.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Xmlsec listed here https://pypi.org/project/xmlsec/. The below command should install for download required native libraries.

```
sudo apt-get install pkg-config libxml2-dev libxmlsec1-dev libxmlsec1-openssl
```

Comment: For python 3.7 I also had to add this:
`apt-get install libpython3.7-dev`


response found [here](https://github.com/MeetMe/newrelic-plugin-agent/issues/151)

Comment: Similar for Python 3.8: `apt-get install libpython3.8-dev`

Answer (score 13):

Fast forward to 2023 and the issue happened w/me on macOS. It seems like we are [Unable to (pip install xmlsec) since brew version 4.0.13](https://github.com/xmlsec/python-xmlsec/issues/254). A variation of *dpritchett*'s workaround plus *johnnymetz*'s comment saved me, which consists on:

> manually reverting to a copy of the last known good pre-1.3.0 xmlsec1 version (1.2.37) Formula:
>
> 1. `brew edit libxmlsec1`; an editor opens up, full of the contents of the latest downloaded xmlsec formula
> 2. paste in the contents of the [last pre-1.3.0 brew formula](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/7f35e6ede954326a10949891af2dba47bbe1fc17/Formula/libxmlsec1.rb)
>    and save it (vim: `wq!`)*
> 3. `brew unlink libxmlsec1`
> 4. Install that local formula: `brew install /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/libxmlsec1.rb`
> 5. `pip install xmlsec`

* On my setup steps 1 & 2 were not necessary; I pasted here a variation of their [answer on the same link](https://github.com/xmlsec/python-xmlsec/issues/254#issuecomment-1507659129)

Comment: Same issue for me on `Homebrew 4.1.20`, and i couldn't get the guides from the others to work, until i found your comment which saved me!.. i was missing to run `brew unlink libxmlsec1` after updating the formula.
And as you said, you combined both dpritchett and johnnymetz suggestions, which I should just have done.. But thanks, now I can continue!

Comment: From the 'answer on the same link', this comment one-liner solved it for me https://github.com/xmlsec/python-xmlsec/issues/254#issuecomment-1726249435

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar issue with installing xmlsec. What did it for me was reinstalling the required native libraries listed here: https://pypi.org/project/xmlsec/

It was as simple as installing: `brew install libxml2 libxmlsec1 pkg-config`

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo apt-get install libxmlsec1-dev pkg-config
```

this will work on  ubuntu / wsl ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

This indicates that the wheels you are trying to install aren't supported by PEP 517.
Try upgrading the following packages then trying to install again

```
pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
```

Comment: Try downgrading pip to 18.1 using  pip install pip==18.1 and installing the libpython dev for your python version.

Comment: solved, I have posted the solution.  thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

i had similar issue but instead of **"pkg-config"** error, i had error with **"xmlsec1"** so i used the command

> sudo apt-get install libxmlsec1-dev pkg-config

as per [Could not find xmlsec1 config. Are libxmlsec1-dev and pkg-config installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51795089/could-not-find-xmlsec1-config-are-libxmlsec1-dev-and-pkg-config-installed/56700040#56700040)

Answer (score 1):

```
yum install libxml2-devel xmlsec1-devel xmlsec1-openssl-devel libtool-ltdl-devel
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution for my MacBook Air (M2, 2022) running macOS Monterey

```
xcode-select --install
brew upgrade
brew install libxml2 libxmlsec1
pip install xmlsec
```

!REBOOT! 
Create virtual env with python 3.10 (probably 3.8/3.9 works too but didn't test)

```
python3.10 -m venv .venv
source .venv/bin/activate
pip install xmlsec
```

Answer (score 0):

Use these `commands` if you are getting this error in mac this will work for sure.

```
xcode-select --install

brew upgrade

brew install libxml2 libxmlsec1

pip install xmlsec
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting below error while installation of [sentry](https://develop.sentry.dev/self-hosted/)

**`ERROR: Could not build wheels for xmlsec which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly`**

It's resolved by @sathiamoorthy above answer.

```
sudo apt-get install pkg-config libxml2-dev libxmlsec1-dev libxmlsec1-openssl
```