# How to install xmlsec on Windows? (pip install xmlsec fails)

Tags: python, windows, pip, command-line-interface

The [xmlsec docs](https://xmlsec.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html#windows) suggest that `pip install xmlsec` should work right out of the box

> Starting with 1.3.7, prebuilt wheels are available for Windows, so running pip install xmlsec should suffice.

However, this threw an error (see below).

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63859803/cant-install-xmlsec-using-pip-command), and I think the answers suggest I need to add native libraries pre-install. But since I'm on Windows and a bit of a beginner I don't know how to install packages like libxml2-dev, libxmlsec1-dev, or libxmlsec1-openssl. `pip install libxml2-dev` doesn't work and AFAIK I can't install `brew` on Windows. I have searched SO and Google extensively and just can't figure it out.

I also tried installing libxml2 separately by extracting some files from the bin folder and adding it to PATH as described here: https://pages.lip6.fr/Jean-Francois.Perrot/XML-Int/Session1/WinLibxml.html, but that didn't work either.

```
Building wheels for collected packages: xmlsec
  Building wheel for xmlsec (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for xmlsec (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [62 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      package init file 'src\xmlsec\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
      running build_ext
      building 'xmlsec' extension
      constants.c

      ...LOTS OF ERRORS/WARNINGS...

      fatal error C1047: The object or library file 'C:\Users\12345\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3tfgg6bc\xmlsec_12345\build\tmp\libs\iconv-1.14.win64\lib\iconv_a.lib' was created with an older compiler than other objects; rebuild old objects and libraries
      LINK : fatal error LNK1257: code generation failed
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\link.exe' failed with exit code 1257
      [end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for xmlsec
Failed to build xmlsec
ERROR: Could not build wheels for xmlsec, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The xmlsec docs suggest that pip install xmlsec should work right out of the box

They are referring to the fact, that they provide `.whl` files for windows. Which you can confirm if you [check the pypi page](https://pypi.org/project/xmlsec/#files). However, only python 3.5-3.9 are supported. If you are running pyhton 3.10, then a compilation from source is attempted.

It looks like `xmlsec` is downloading pre-built libraries from `https://github.com/bgaifullin/libxml2-win-binaries/releases/` which cannot be linked with what your compiler creates on-the-fly (see your error message) because of a compiler version mismatch:

```
fatal error C1047: The object or library file 'C:\Users\12345\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3tfgg6bc\xmlsec_12345\build\tmp\libs\iconv-1.14.win64\lib\iconv_a.lib' was created with an older compiler than other objects; rebuild old objects and libraries
```

I think the easiest way around this would be to simply downgrade your python to 3.9 and then install with pip. Downloading/compiling your own version of the required libs would not solve the issue, since `xmlsec` always downloads the version it thinks it needs

Comment: Thanks, I missed checking the version.

Comment: It might work now:
https://github.com/xmlsec/python-xmlsec/issues/204#issuecomment-1221409413